# Jquery drag drop z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a Jquery Drag Drop UI script on page elements that are restricted by a container, I was just wondering if there was a way to always place the dragged div on top of the other child draggable elements.

**Javascript function:**

```
function dragIT(parent){
$("#"+parent).draggable({ containment: "#dashboard", scroll: false });
}
```

This function is called by the child/div -  onmousedown / ondrag. However, dragged elements are sometimes hidden behind other divs which is something I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#visual-feedback has an example

```
function dragIT(parent){
$("#"+parent).draggable({ containment: "#dashboard", scroll: false, stack:"#"+parent+" div" });
}
```

Comment: Tried using the code provided. z-index still not automatically setting

Comment: @Andrew did you check the jquery reference page? You didn't post any HTML so there may be something I missing because of that.